# Writing program better

Tags: c++

im really new to programming and really want some help:). I have made a program that finds the average out of 5 numbers. I was wondering i i could get some help to make this program more efficient. Im using c++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    int num4;
    int num5;
    int Anum;
    int AAnum;

    cout << "pick your first number";
    cin >> num1;

    cout << "pick your second numer";
    cin >> num2;

    cout << "pick you third number";
    cin >> num3;

    cout << "pick your forth number";
    cin >> num4;

    cout << "pick you fifth number";
    cin >> num5;

    Anum = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5;
    AAnum = Anum / 5;
    cout << "the average number is " << AAnum;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need 5 variables. You could do this in a loop with a sum a single input variable and a count. Adding the count allows for a number of inputs that is different from 5.

Comment: Create and array instead of using 5 different variables. Then you can iterate over the array with a sum and at the and divide it with the size of your array (number of the elements).

Comment: One of the most important principles in programming is to let the code *do work for you* rather than you having to *work to make code*. What I mean by this is when you program think in terms of results, and work backwards to the data structures best suited to hold those results. From there you can usually come up with a minimal amount of code that achieves your desired results. In this case you don't need to capture separate values, you can just sum. You could also use an array, or in C++ terms, `std::vector`, to capture them if necessary.

Comment: Look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to programming! How about something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main() {
    double average = 0.0;

    const int num_to_average = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_to_average; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Pick number " << i << ": ";
        double num;
        cin >> num;

        average += num;
    }
    average /= num_to_average;
    cout << "the average number is " << average << end;

    return 0;
```

That way the loop does all the heavy lifting for you so instead of 5 separate variables, you can add them all into a single variable (and then computes the average at the end).

**Edit**: included @tadman's `double` instead of `float` suggestion.

Comment: Tip: Use `double` instead of `float`. It's not the 1970s and the handful of extra bytes required won't blow your stack.

Comment: You could do that in way shorter. For example in your last cout line you can write     `average /= num_to_average;` + Using float is not very nice. Double has 2x more precision then float. In general a double has 15 decimal digits of precision, while float has 7. A double is 64 and single precision (float) is 32 bits. The double has a bigger mantissa (the integer bits of the real number). Any inaccuracies will be smaller in the double.

Comment: Furthermore, don't use += to sum lots of floating point numbers, as the errors accumulate quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The runtime for this program is going to be as good as it's going to get. Each statement will be executed in O(1) time and the runtime performance probably isn't going to improve unless you change the way you prompt for the numbers (i.e. "Enter 5 numbers separated by spaces" and then do cin >> num1 >> num2 >> ...)

Now if you want a better way to write your algorithm, try an array.

At the top:

```
#define NUMBEROFNUMBERS 5

int inputArray[NUMBEROFNUMBERS];

for(int i = 0; i < NUMBEROFNUMBERS; i++) {
cout << "Pick #" << i + 1 << ": ";
cin >> inputArray[i];
}
```

And then calculate your average by looping through the array and outputting the result.

Comment: In C++ it's bad form to use `#define`. Instead use `const`.

Comment: Actually, use ```constexpr``` for compile-time constants.

Answer (score 0):

It's a short and elegant way to do that if you exactly know the elements of your array.

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    double result = 0;
    const double myFirstArray[5] = { 5, 10, 22, 44, 5 };
    for (int i = 0; i < std::size(myFirstArray); i++) {
        result+=myFirstArray[i];
    }
    std::cout << "Average: " <<result/ std::size(myFirstArray);
    return 0;
}
```